# wc -c gives one more than I expected, why is that?

Tags: command-line, word-count, wc

```
echo '2003'| wc -c
```

I thought it would give me 4, but it turned to be 5, what is that additional byte?

Comment: there are a lot of duplicates: [linux shell wc -c count characters +1](https://superuser.com/q/525902/241386), [Why `wc -c` always count 1 more character?](https://serverfault.com/q/287370/343888)

Answer (score 3):

Because **echo** will get a new line.

> echo "2014" | wc -c

it will get 5

> printf "2014" | wc -c

it will get 4 where **printf** will not add a new line.

Answer (score 1):

[`echo`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) contains a built-in switch, `-n`, to remove newline. So running:

```
echo -n "2021" | wc -c
```

Will output the expected `4`.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` adds new line  which is causing the issue.
As mentioned by "KyChen", you can use `printf` or:

```
a="2014 ;
echo $a |awk '{print length}'
```